# ng test ELIFECYCLE error when run from npm script, but not when run directly from command line

Tags: npm, angular-cli

Within my Angular (v10) project, I am trying to write a script for automated testing. But when executing from that script, I'm getting an npm ELIFECYCLE error. Works fine if I perform the same command directly from command line though.

For example

```
$ ng test {module} --code-coverage --no-watch
```

works correctly.

But

```
$ npm run blah
```

where, "blah": "ng test {module} --code-coverage --no-watch" in my package.json results in

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

And there are no helpful details in the error message or log file.

Appreciate any insights for this issue. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Karma to run your test ?

I had the same issue, my tests were running with Karma and by default, it exits with an error if there is no test to run.

To avoid this problem, you can add `failOnEmptyTestSuite: false` to your `karma.conf.js`